# Transitioning from pre-existing bullnose tile edge to drywall

Tags: drywall, tile, transition

How can I create a clean line between a pre-existing bullnose tile edge and the drywall that is to be skim coated and painted?

I was disgusted with the upper half of my bathroom walls which were covered with decades-old curled wallpaper, and tore it down. I want to keep the bullnose tile (covered in painter's tape in attached photo) but don't want to do any tile work.

Any thoughts on this would be well appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is you have the edge taped, remove any loose material and skim coat. Do your major painting remove the tape and using a quality brush hand paint the line at the tile will provide the best transition between the tile and sheetrock.

Comment: @EdBeal, thank you for commenting. I guess my issue is a lack of confidence in precision painting and also uncertainty as to whether caulking would be ideally called for here at some step.

May I ask why you suggest removing the tape and not just painting right to the edge of the painter's tape or slightly beyond it? Is it because one would be prone to peeling off the desired newly painted surface as a consequence of removing the tape? I had similar concerns with the skim coating compound encroaching on the painter's tape territory.

Comment: You want a clean transition I have found skim coating makes a bit of a mess especially if sanded, after removing the tape using a high quality brush and going slow cutting in the edge with paint will provide the cleanest edge in my experiances and I am a really sloppy painter but find this method is the best for no lines that the tape can leave. It would not hurt to pull the tape that is there and put a fresh layer off 1/16 inch just in case.

Comment: @EdBeal, I'll definitely go down this road. Just bought a fancy 2 inch angled sash brush for the occasion. Thanks again!